# How to store Firebase data to access easily and fast in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on my user profile page on my app and I need to retrieve data from Firebase and display the data on my user profile page. I have managed to retrieve the data successfully from the database but the problem is that every time I go to the user profile page, it takes a little time to access the information in the database, so as soon as you go to the user profile page, the page will be empty. How can I avoid this?

Put another way, is there a way to access the data and store before going to the user profile page and then displaying the data that is stored? Here is my code:

```
// Setup the name label
func setupNameLabel() {

    // Access the database and get the current user's name
    Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID!).child("Name").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        guard let name = snapshot.value as? String else { return }

        self.nameLabel.text = name
    }
    view.addSubview(nameLabel) 
}

// Setup the username label
func setupUsernameLabel() {

    // Access the database and get the current user's username
    Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID!).child("Username").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        guard let username = snapshot.value as? String else { return }

        self.usernameLabel.text = username
    }
    view.addSubview(usernameLabel)        
}

// Setup the email label
func setupEmailLabel() {

    // Access the database and get the current user's email
    Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID!).child("Email").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        guard let email = snapshot.value as? String else { return }

        self.emailLabel.text = email
    }        
    view.addSubview(emailLabel)        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try To make a Model and then using Single Method and Get Data with Completion

```
func getData(forUserID: String, completion: @escaping (Model) -> Swift.Void, error: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check models of Salada cocoapod, please.

https://github.com/1amageek/Salada

Especially the models like Relation, Disposer, Set, Array, File are very beautiful.